# Do users get rep for downvoting questions?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting

I feel as though a lot of questions (especially mine) get downvotes for no reason (my opinion).

I am still fairly new to SO and was wondering if users get rep for downvoting questions.

Comment: Noperoni, batman. In fact, you *lose* rep for downvoting *answers*. There's no rep change for questions. Here's a duplicate question on the *other* Meta site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93023/why-do-i-not-lose-reputation-when-i-downvote-posts

Comment: Ah I see, so the users who cast these down votes have to give up their rep. @CaseyFalk

Comment: Downvotes on questions = no change in reputation, downvotes on answers = -1 reputation

Comment: Not quite, @StackXchangeT: there's **no** rep change for the *voter* related to questions.

Comment: Thank you for that link it was helpful @CaseyFalk

Comment: After looking at the three questions on your account that I could see with downvotes, it looks like lack of what you've tried. I don't know for sure as I'm not the downvoter, but that might be something to consider with future questions.

Comment: I don't think I will be asking questions for a long time, I just can't seem to come up with questions that reputable people such as yourself will not downvote. @Kendra

Comment: @StackXchangeT Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) link out. It should give you a few pointers, if you haven't read it before. In addition, at the bottom are some links to extra resources to help you form good questions. Just give it time and some faith, and you'll be asking well-received questions in no time. :) (PS. I'm not _that_ reputable, I just read Meta a lot so I know how a lot of people are currently reacting to questions. Though this question was poorly researched, I think you did well to not complain about downvotes, but rather ask about a possible motive.)

Comment: This question was made as a kind of "spur of the moment" I already obviated that it would receive negative attention(down votes) but I appreciate your feedback and your link! @Kendra

Comment: If you're new and have questions like this, you would be well-served by going through the [help], or at least searching it first before posting here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down answers your question. It's also a good idea to look through [Meta.SE] for policy and more in-depth functionality information.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not at all.

In fact, you *lose* reputation for downvoting answers. Downvotes are "free" on questions.

See [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

If your question is being downvoted, it may be poorly researched/formatted/worded. If you see downvotes on your question, it should mean "What's wrong with my question? I should edit it," not "Those people are so inconsiderate! Idiots: they must get reputation for it."

If you're going to ask us to explain our downvotes, well, [we've had that discussion before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes).

Comment: I've seen a couple of those other questions where people asked for explanations, and I don't knock people for downvoting it's just rather irritating to know that no one really respects my questions and/or feel as though it was not researched enough.

Comment: @StackXchangeT There's a very unfortunate reason for that. The problem is that SO gets over 7000 questions a day, much of which is of terrible quality. The handful of experienced users effectively get overwhelmed and lose their patience while sorting through the mountains of crap. End result: People get snappy and downvote/closevote happy. The downvoting and closing also tells other users, "This is a terrible question, so don't waste your time here. Go look at something else."

Comment: @StackXchangeT What Mysticial said + the fact that there are certain things about a question (poor grammar/formatting) that make it quickly evident to users who have been here before that a particular question is not worth the effort: fixing the little things makes a big difference.

Comment: I can see how easily an eager to help programmer can get overwhelmed with the immense amount of questions. @Mysticial

Comment: Yeah if I ever ask a question I will keep that in mind. @AstroCB